# View variables not interpreted as variable

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Some variables seem to not be interpreted as variables but as string

I'm starting on Django and am following a tutorial in which I came across this piece of code :

In template :

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in couleurs.items %}
    <li style="color:# {{ key }} ">{{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I should add that in my code editor (VSC) the " "color:# {{ key }} " " part is in a different color then the rest

In view :

```
def rainbow(request):
    couleurs = {
    'FF0000':'rouge', 
    'ED7F10':'orange', 
    'FFFF00':'jaune', 
    '00FF00':'vert', 
    '0000FF':'bleu', 
    '4B0082':'indigo', 
    '660099':'violet',
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/rainbow.html', locals())
```

The errors displayed are in the 3rd line of the template : 
   _The error displayed when I hover my mouse over the # is "property value expected"
   _And the one for } is "at-rule or selector expected"

The code should print the colors in color (ex : red in red etc...)

Thanks in advance !
English not first language btw so sorry if I misspelled stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a *space* between the hash (`#`) and the color core, you should not do that. The css `# ff0000` is indeed wrong, you should use `#ff0000` instead. You can render this with:

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in couleurs.items %}
    <li style="color:#{{ key }} ">{{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Actually it's a mistake on my part you are right but even without the space the errors were still there until I downloaded an add-on for Django on vsc, afterward it worked perfectly anyway you are right the code doesn't work with the space :)